# How the conditions ( sc == rs + 1 || sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS) can be achieved in addCount function of ConcurrentHashMap( JDK1.8 or later)

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.concurrent

> I read the source code of `addCount` function in  ConcurrentHashMap, 
>   but I don't understand when the conditions `( sc == rs + 1 || sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS)` can be achieved.
>
> why not use `sc  ==  ( rs<<<RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT ) +1 || sc  ==  ( rs<<<RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT ) + MAX_RESIZERS`

In the `addCount(long x, int check)` function of ConcurrentHashMap(JDK1.8 or later),  there are some code as the following

```
if(check >=0{
    Node<K, V>[] tab, nt;
    int n, sc;
    while (s >= (long) (sc = sizeCtl) && (tab = table) != null &&
            (n = tab.length) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
        int rs = resizeStamp(n);

        if (sc < 0) {
            // the problem is here : 
            // the condition sc == rs + 1 ||  sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS
            // seems always to be false
            if ((sc >>> RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) != rs || sc == rs + 1 ||
                    sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS || (nt = nextTable) == null ||
                    transferIndex <= 0)

                break;
            if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1))
                transfer(tab, nt);
        } else if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc,
                (rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2))
            transfer(tab, null);
        s = sumCount();
    }
}
```

I have done some reserch job to understand how resizeStamp(n)  works and how varaible `sizeCtl` works.

So basically, when one thread first get the opportunity to resize the bucket array in ConcurrentHashMap, it will do operation

`U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc,(rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2)`

to make the `sizeCtl` become a negative value which can denote that there are some thread doing resizing on the bucket array.

when `sizeCtl` become negative, the lower 16 bit contains information about how many threads are doinig resizing concurrently.

Here are my thoughts :

since varible `sc` is a local int variable as the code shows  `int n, sc;`

after `s >= (long) (sc = sizeCtl)` is executed ,

the value of `sc` will never be changed for a theard in one iteration.

I listed all the code snnippet that have chance to change sizeCtl in one round while loop

Two pieces in the `addCount` function :

- `else if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, (rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2))`

  - the purpose of it is trying to contend on the opportunity to be the first thread that do resizing
- `if ( U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1) )`

  - the purpose of it is trying to contend on the opportunity to help resizing

Three pieces in `transfer` fucntion

- `sizeCtl = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

  - this is to cope with OOP error
- `sizeCtl = (n << 1) - (n >>> 1);`

  - this will happen when all elements in old table have been transfered to new table , the last thread which has not returned from `transfer` will set sizeCtl to next threshhold, which is `0.75 * (2n)`, notice `n` is old capcity. `2n` is new capacity
- `U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc = sizeCtl, sc - 1)`

  - this is to do resizing thread number control, which can identify one Thread is going to return from transfer

According to the all above info, I found :

After enter the if branch `if (sc < 0)`, which means the `sizeCtl` have been assigned by `(rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2`,  `sc` shuold be a "large" negative number with higher 16 bits computed from `resizeStamp(n)`. The conditions

```
   sc == rs + 1 
 ||sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS
```

could never be achieved given the fact that

- The `MAX_RESIZERS` equals 65535
- The maximum value of `rs` is `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ) | (1 << (RESIZE_STAMP_BITS - 1))`, which equals 32769

I think the following conditions make more sense

`sc  ==  ( rs<<<RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT ) +1` to judge whether all threads finished resizing

`sc  ==  ( rs<<<RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT ) + MAX_RESIZERS` to judge whether resizing threads has already achieved maxiumum limit MAX_RESIZERS.

Can someone help me to explain if I am wrong, thanks a lot !

### **The follwing is a little experiment I did to verify my thought**

Thanks for the suggestion  from Carlos Heuberger

> can you post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to demonstrate the problem?

- First, copy the `ConcurrentHashMap` source code to your own package
- Second, do some necessary modification to make it can be compiled (eg: change package declaration, make Unsafe instance works, copy ThreadLocalRandom to your package as well, since the ConcurrentHashMap used ThreadLocalRandom.probe() function, which is not public )
- Third, reduce MAX_RESIZERS to 2, as the documentation shows, this **should** ensure there are at most 2 threads can do resizing concurrently

  `private static final int MAX_RESIZERS = 2;`
- Fourth, add the following code snippet into the customized ConcurrentHashMap class

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  ConcurrentHashMap hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap(8);

  for(int i = 0; i< 300; i++)
  {
      new Thread() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              hashMap.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(),"id: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
          }
      }.start();
  }
  ```

  }
- Fifth, add the following code snippet into the `transfer` function of ConcurrentHashMap . To suspend any thread that entered into `transfer`

  ```
      if (nextTab == null) {            // initiating
      try {
          @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          Node<K,V>[] nt = (Node<K,V>[])new Node<?,?>[n << 1];
          nextTab = nt;
      } catch (Throwable ex) {      // try to cope with OOME
          sizeCtl = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
          return;
      }
      nextTable = nextTab;
      transferIndex = n;
  }
  //  The following added code here is to suspend Threads !!!!
  try {
      String s = new String();
      synchronized (s)
      {
          s.wait();
      }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```
- Six, add the Thread break point in the following code line in `addCount` function

  - ( Tip: I used Idea Intellij , choose "Thread" option can suspend each thread in your application , otherwise it will only suspend only the first Thread which executed to the break point)

    ```
                if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1))
                transfer(tab, nt);
    ```

    [image]
- Then run the main function, you will see more than 2 threads entered `transfer` function, which means MAX_RESIZERS does not take any effect.

Comment: Is this a question? Or a bug report? Frankly, it's not clear. Please read about [ask] questions here.

Comment: This is a question, I wish someone help me confirm if I am wrong about it

Comment: can you post a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger  I think this problem could only be verified by the scenario that there are more than `MAX_RESIZERS` threads doing resizing on the same ConcurrentHashMap, it's hard to simulate this scenario.  Because usually, before more threads join the same round of resizing process,  the  resizing has been finished

Comment: @ Ed Cottrell♦ , I have edited the problem to clearify it.

Comment: @skomisa thanks for your guidance, already deleted

Comment: minimal -> eventually reduce `MAX_RESIZERS`? (after copying the source code)

Comment: @ Carlos Heuberger Thanks for your inspiration, I copied the source code , and did a little experiment. I will add it in my question

Comment: just noted now: `while (... (sc = sizeCtl) ...)` can/will change `sc` on each iteration if `sizeCtl` is changed by any other Thread. `sizeCtl` is changed in `transfer` (without synchronization, if I'm correct), so I suspect that breaking inside of transfer is preventing it from being set correctly to avoid other Threads... but I didn't get time to analyze  the code thoroughly

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger thanks for your info, I missed that point. But I have checked the `transfer` code thoroughly, still cannot find the chance the conditions could be staisfied. I will add this info in my question

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted this question as a bug report to Oracle. It has passed the evaluation and become visible on jdk bug database with bug id : JDK-8214427

Here is the link for the bug report : [BUG: JDK-8214427](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8214427).  Notice the fix method given in the bug report is wrong due to my mistake

Summary :

The conditions

```
( sc == rs + 1 || sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS)
```

should be changed to

```
sc  ==  ( rs<<<RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT ) +1 || sc  ==  ( rs<<<RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT ) + MAX_RESIZERS
```

[Fixed JDK-12 code is now available here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/9af672cab7cb/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java)

```
 if (check >= 0) {
            Node<K,V>[] tab, nt; int n, sc;
            while (s >= (long)(sc = sizeCtl) && (tab = table) != null &&
                   (n = tab.length) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
                int rs = resizeStamp(n) << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT;
                if (sc < 0) {
                    if (sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS || sc == rs + 1 ||
                        (nt = nextTable) == null || transferIndex <= 0)
                        break;
                    if (U.compareAndSetInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1))
                        transfer(tab, nt);
                }
                else if (U.compareAndSetInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, rs + 2))
                    transfer(tab, null);
                s = sumCount();
            }
        }
```